# What type of application to choose

Tags: facebook, api, profile

I want to create facebook application that will allow to insert some data from my site to user's profile. User can choose to set up application. The users enters his ID on my site and when user's profile is viewed there is block of data loaded from my site (specified to the ID).
Is this possible to create such application with facebook ? If no the what type of application is closest to this? My site users want to display their profiles from my site inside their facebook profiles , so facebook friends can see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to add some additional data on the users Facebook profile, something like if Stackoverflow would add their flair on the Facebook profile.

I don't think this is possible, but you have a few alternatives:

- Make the user post out a link to his profile on your site to his Facebook Wall, [more details here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/).
- Integrate your site to the new Open Graph Objects. Open Graph Objects will create a box on the users profile for your application which shows the users activity in your application. You should check out the [demos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/samples/) and [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/) for more information about this.

> The users enters his ID on my site and when user's profile is viewed there is block of data loaded from my site

You can't do anything like this, you will need to use the authentication flow provided by Facebook in order to get access to the Facebook user data and then tie up the Facebook user to "your user", [see documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

When it comes to what type of app you should create, there is basically only one type of app with some different options. But you should focus on the ["Facebook for websites" documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/).